# want to write a class such that variable and methods declared in that class is used in multiple classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to write the class in such a way that the value of the variable "monthlyInfoFile" is used in many other classes.
I have written the classes as below, can someone please help me out to get the best possible approach of doing this.
In GenerateMonthsInfo class, i'm calling other class method "monthsInfo" in which i need to get the value of montlyInfoFile variable declared in DetailShared class.

I want to write the methods and variable declared in DetailShared class such that method/variable should be accessed in other classes and variable "monthlyInfoFile" once gets the value should be able to use that value throughout the flow of the application.

DetailShared.java - value which needs to be shared

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

class DetailShared {
    static boolean monthlyInfoFile;

    public static void checkinMonth(String path) {
        File informationFile = new File(filePath + "\\months.txt");
        if (informationFile.exists()) {
            monthlyInfoFile = true;
            checkOtherInformation();
        } else {
            monthlyInfoFile = false;
        }

    }

    public static void checkOtherInformation(String path) {

    //do something
    }
}

class PopulateTheBasics {
    // methods
    public void calculateTheBilling() {
        // want to get the value of monthlyInfoFile
    }
}
```

GenerateMonthsInfo.java - value needs to be taken from  DetailShared class

```
class GenerateMonthsInfo {
    void monthsInfo(String path) {
        // want to get the value of monthlyInfoFile
        new DetailShared().checkinMonth(path);
        new PopulateTheBasics().calculateTheBilling();
    }
    void populateExcel(){
      if(DetailShared.monthlyInfoFile){
       //do some logic
       } else{ //some logic }
    }
}
```

Test.java - it calls GenerateMonthsInfo to get the value

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new GenerateMonthsInfo().monthsInfo("c:/path/details");
    }
}
```

Comment: Move this to CodeReview network

Comment: Please see the above post, formatted the code and made simple to understand. Any inputs are helpful.

Comment: whatever you are doing is correct the variable monthlyInfoFile is static so it can be accessed across all the classes. you can call like below,
DetailShared. monthlyInfoFile - this will give the value across all the class.

Comment: @ArunPrasat - I am confused with the access specifiers for the variable and methods declared in DetailShared class..can i make any method as private or final in DetailShared class.

Comment: I believe the answer you want is already in your own question.
See **GenerateMonthsInfo.java** you are already using the value of **monthlyInfoFile** from **DetailShared**, so if you want to use the same value at **PopulateTheBasics** just do the same. It _WILL_ share the same value because it is static.

Comment: I'm not seeing any problem here. If you want opinions on how to improve, move this question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If there is a problem, please clarify.

Comment: Yes , I want to know if I can improve my above code in any possible way.. I know how access modifiers works but just want to know if I can write more better way.. I will try to move to code review else any comments on this thread will be useful for future stackflow users

Answer (score 0):

Might not totally answer your question, but according to your last comments I believe what you want/need to understand is the concept of Packages in Java, and controlling Access Modifiers.

A lot of starter Java coder are usually only coding on a single folder, and thus doesn't learn the concept yet.

Here is a few links for you to read on :

- [Java Packages](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages)
- [Access Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)